# Check the status of a checkbox

Tags: checkbox, checked

I have Form Settings with a check box and Form Research with procedures.
If check box status is checked do procedure n.1, else do procedure n.2.
How can i do that?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDGy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1xKt.png)

Comment: What language are you using? What research have you done? What code have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: HTML, Java, C#, PHP ? Please provide some context about the technology.

Comment: c#     
I do not find  checkbox if i write my code in a different form

Comment: This would be an easy question to answer if we had more context :)

Comment: In img 1 in frmMain in private void ricerca click i want to write a procedure if the check box state of Inserimento manuale in img 2 is checked

Comment: i add two images